# How to delete multi selected check-boxes when a delete button is clicked in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, redux

I have multiple check boxes and a single delete button at the top. After making the selection I should remove the selected check-boxes . How can I do that in React Js .

Comment: can you post some sample code?

Comment: I dont have my code right now . I just imported JSON file with some users data . The UI displays the checkboxes with the user names and a delete button at the top.  I need to remove the check boxes selected when the delete button is clicked .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
      list: [
        { id: 1, label: 'Reading', value: false },
        { id: 2, label: 'Playing game', value: false },
        { id: 3, label: 'Listening to music', value: false },
        { id: 4, label: 'Watching TV', value: true }
      ]
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        list: prevState.list.map(
          li => (li.id === +id ? { ...li,
            value: !li.value
          } : li)
        )
      };
    });
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        list: prevState.list.filter(li => !li.value)
      };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.list.map(e => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={e.id}
              checked={e.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor={e.id}>{e.label}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: See this: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I used the `filter()` method to "remove" the checked items.

Comment: sorry not the handle click .. this one
handleChange = e => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        list: prevState.list.map(
          li => (li.id === +id ? { ...li,
            value: !li.value
          } : li)
        )
      };
    });
  };

Comment: the idea behind is the combination of [Handling Multiple Inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) and [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: and [Using `map()` to update value of a list-item property](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist#reducers-todos-js)

Comment: my checkbox not getting checked but no error in the console .

Comment: @Rennie I think you should make another question with the error, the code, the expected behavior and the actual behavior ;)